# Opacity bug in chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

When opacity is given to odd number of child flex elements a white space appears randomly between the elements in Chrome. It is not there in Firefox or Safari.

The child class has following styles:

```
.dot{
    flex:1;
    background:red;
    opacity:0.5;
    cursor:pointer;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
   }
```

Find the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cuqL15d9/1/) here

As mentioned in one of the answers it is the issue with odd number of children in flex and even width. Is there any workaround other than using rgba.

Comment: i see nothing ...

Comment: No white space here.

Comment: was it checked in chrome ?

Comment: Its working..... You Can use @mixin chrome-styles { }

Comment: I suppose you are referring to what looks like a 1px wide white line inside the right border? Yes, I can confirm that I see that, too - but it remains even when all opacity is removed, see https://jsfiddle.net/cuqL15d9/2/

Comment: Which version of chrome are you talking about as I can't see it in version 63.0.3239.132

Comment: im on the same version too, but i can see white borders for the children inside parent. @karen

Comment: @Cbroe I am not able to see that border actually.

Comment: Well then show us a screenshot please, so that we can know what you are actually talking about.

Comment: I am not able to upload screenshots

Comment: You seem to be lacking any HTML that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @TobySpeight yea this is more of a css issue

Comment: The only way I was able to see the white line was by setting the background of dot to black and the white line becomes obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.parent` was set to a `width: 200px;` and the .dot is having `flex: 1;` which is adding `flex-basis: 100%;`. As the number of children `.dot` is an odd number (7 in this case), it causes a percentage rounding issue with chrome.
Refer [link](https://css-tricks.com/percentage-bugs-in-webkit).

Comment: is there any solution to this for odd number of children?

Comment: @silver - Can you consider increasing the width from 200px to 210px (a multiple of 7)?

Comment: thing is width is gonna be auto, i just added a width here for demonstration purpose. Even the number of child elements are gonna be dynamic.

Comment: @silver - In that case, you could set a high `min-width` to `.dot` like `1000px` and set `overflow: hidden;` to the `.parent`. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cuqL15d9/9) here.

Comment: i need the parent to wrap the child elements, this is supposed to be part of dot indicator for carousels and similar components.

Comment: @silver - In that case, you may resort to the `background-color` property than `opacity.` [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cuqL15d9/10) here.

Comment: yea using rgba for background-color is one option, but i am seeing is there any work around using opacity itself.

Comment: The answer is a no, sadly :(

Answer (score 0):

Previous answer do not solve the issue.

Here's a screenshot for people who can't reproduce bug:

[image]

I found another fast and easy solution. `opacity` property somehow add whitespace between flex items.

So you can just use `background: rgba()` instead of it.

```css
.parent{
 width:200px;
 height:15px;
 display:flex;
 border:1px solid black;
}
.dot{
 flex:1;
 background-color:rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
 cursor:pointer;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}
.dot:hover{
  background-color:rgba(255,0,0,1);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
 <div class="dot"></div>
 <div class="dot"></div>
 <div class="dot"></div>
 <div class="dot"></div>
 <div class="dot"></div>
 <div class="dot"></div>
 <div class="dot"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Isn't there anyway around using rgba ?

Comment: If you want to use `opacity` try just add to `.dot` styles `outline: 1px solid rgba(255, 0, 0, 0);`